# Make iFrames not load on page start up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

So my website has a bunch of iFrames that load when the website loads but they are all hidden until they click a button to show them.

The problem is all of the iframes are loading at once so its resource heavy. I would like the frames only to ACTUALLY load when you click the button and possibly unload when they click the button again to hide them.

Here is my current code of just one of the iFrames:

```
 <li data-value="iconchange"><img src="modules/icons/icons/calculator.png" width="65"  onclick = "calcShow()" class="calculator"></li> &nbsp;
```

Here is the Script to make it hide on launch

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function calcShow() {
  var calc = document.getElementById('calcShow');
  if (calc.className == 'show') {
    calc.className = 'hide';
  }
  else if (calc.className == 'hide') {
    calc.className = 'show';
  }
}
</script>
```

And then the DIV with the include

```
 <div id="calcShow" class="hide"><br><br><br>
       <?php

                        include("modules/calc/calc.html");
        ?>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

okey so you want to load the iframe on button click here is an example try something like this

```
<div id="iframeContainer"></div>
<input type="btn" clas="btn btn-default" value="Click Me"/>
```

and on the script side

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#btn').on('click', function (e) { 
if(!$('#iframeContainer').length)
{
$('<iframe>', {
   src: 'Your link',
   width:'1062',
   height: '600',
   id:  'myFrame',
   frameborder: 0  
   }).appendTo('#iframeContainer'); 
});
}
else
{
if(!$('#iframeContainer').hasClass('hidden'))
     {
     $('#iframeContainer').addClass('hidden')
     }
 else
   {
    $('#iframeContainer').removeClass('hidden')
   }
 }
})
</script>
```

Comment: You should prefer this solution over the solution with an empty src-Tag.

Comment: Could you show me an example on how I would implement with the code I provided above? I'm kinda confused. It's a picture is what they are clicking not a button. Much appreciated.

Comment: dude all you need to do is 1.give that img an id 2 create an empty div so that you can place your iframe there

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="" class="iframe_class" />
```

on click function

```
$('.iframe_class').attr('src', 'http://url.some.thing')
```